# Ggplot Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

My ggplot code below is working on my Mac, but isn't working on my Linux instance.

As per the title, I get the error `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y and colour` with this code.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

plot_total <-
          demo %>%
          as.data.frame() %>%
          ggplot(aes(log2(baseMean), log2FoldChange, color=padj < 0.01,
                     text = paste(" log2(baseMean):", formatC(log2(baseMean), format = "e", digits = 2), "\n",
                                  "log2FoldChange:", formatC(log2FoldChange, format = "e", digits = 2), "\n",
                                  "Gene Name:", Gene, "\n",
                                  "EnsGeneID:", ENSG))) +
          geom_point(data = . %>% filter(!padj<0.01), cex = 0.1, size=0.1) +
          geom_point(data = . %>% filter(is.na(padj)), cex = 0.1, size=0.1) +
          geom_point(data = . %>% filter(padj<0.01), cex = 1, size=1) +
          scale_color_manual(values=c("FALSE" = "#30B7BC", "TRUE" = "#DE653A", "NA" = "#B3B3B3")) +
          labs(title = "Treated vs. Control", x = "log2Expression") +
          theme_bw() +
          NULL
    
    ggplotly(plot_total,
             tooltip = "text",
             type = 'scattergl') %>% 
      config(displaylogo = FALSE,
             modeBarButtonsToRemove = c('sendDataToCloud', 'select2d', 'lasso2d')) %>% 
      toWebGL()
```

The culprit seems to be the `text` variable. I have tried placing this variable inside each `geom_point(aes())` where I'm filtering the data, but I get the same error.  This is a small subset of the data:

| ENSG | Gene | baseMean | log2FoldChange | lfcSE | stat | pvalue | padj |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ENSG00000000003.15 | TSPAN6 | 2106.78150011798 | -0.214594792659649 | 0.0830671887250501 | -2.58338816990607 | 0.00978351787155086 | 0.0632360231867511 |
| ENSG00000000005.6 | TNMD | 3.51684529099911 | 1.33352064084301 | 0.680105184521041 | 1.96075647001887 | 0.0499074381755472 | NA |
| ENSG00000000419.13 | DPM1 | 1156.63019852077 | -0.184963193359761 | 0.0697284461507299 | -2.65262175726578 | 0.00798693161495278 | 0.0556311026232396 |
| ENSG00000000457.14 | SCYL3 | 270.00909649605 | -0.0558608208897551 | 0.0945944838404759 | -0.590529369386473 | 0.554835801729326 | 0.752831745155342 |
| ENSG00000000460.17 | C1orf112 | 423.916241362646 | 0.00337838445840835 | 0.0904413626324259 | 0.0373544179352855 | 0.970202416501722 | 0.985859261611512 |
| ENSG00000000938.13 | FGR | 1.4952572446323 | 0.189881722278028 | 1.0225523780978 | 0.18569388360453 | 0.852684825077251 | NA |
| ENSG00000000971.16 | CFH | 8.35615935084791 | -0.407549583396925 | 0.407283654269094 | -1.00065293346552 | 0.316994629452948 | NA |
| ENSG00000001036.14 | FUCA2 | 3286.83167836124 | -0.113975393359072 | 0.0532994402577163 | -2.13839756680318 | 0.032484489796959 | 0.140642991190518 |
| ENSG00000001084.13 | GCLC | 1525.77400190981 | -0.0964283327267667 | 0.0697918041485629 | -1.38165697108938 | 0.167077052186927 | 0.387307483908263 |
| ENSG00000001167.14 | NFYA | 775.15489019341 | -0.0282781481284204 | 0.108165475282215 | -0.2614341411124 | 0.793757731444887 | 0.89507246376111 |
| ENSG00000001460.18 | STPG1 | 1105.63501614957 | 0.154649228441584 | 0.0886193148590866 | 1.74509618684697 | 0.0809681272261289 | 0.252149556355932 |
| ENSG00000001461.17 | NIPAL3 | 1755.50307288809 | -0.0313646069063427 | 0.0699845764115142 | -0.448164560172753 | 0.654034437625039 | 0.815455908057006 |
| ENSG00000001497.17 | LAS1L | 2188.7653564921 | -0.0523385791864584 | 0.0712541067124691 | -0.734534212851194 | 0.462623216454675 | 0.684620504636789 |
| ENSG00000001561.7 | ENPP4 | 830.269207280792 | -0.298210398294484 | 0.10493466780185 | -2.84186727362211 | 0.00448501591940391 | 0.0369683950248886 |
| ENSG00000001617.12 | SEMA3F | 507.841167325578 | 0.220524182082938 | 0.107840828258815 | 2.04490438031211 | 0.0408642859982967 | 0.163022035306157 |
| ENSG00000001626.16 | CFTR | 130.392965133479 | 2.01581704225126 | 0.726570495644851 | 2.7744273327011 | 0.00552989865962655 | 0.0428809290359717 |
| ENSG00000001629.10 | ANKIB1 | 1378.77776720815 | -0.00295677498548296 | 0.0912941535974317 | -0.0323873421130675 | 0.974163156724246 | 0.987546941506975 |
| ENSG00000001631.16 | KRIT1 | 1.9871339581813 | -0.292437549054293 | 0.868146512011618 | -0.336852760459377 | 0.736227897832157 | NA |
| ENSG00000002016.18 | RAD52 | 680.085519620988 | 0.373097140440191 | 0.156407957981969 | 2.3854102134829 | 0.0170600862524028 | 0.0916401980775939 |
| ENSG00000002079.14 | MYH16 | 1.86080100353 | -0.182051454327792 | 1.01764691310774 | -0.178894518307764 | 0.858020527111129 | NA |
| ENSG00000002330.14 | BAD | 551.20996778861 | -0.0039768348985057 | 0.12107851487019 | -0.0328450914909992 | 0.973798119784072 | 0.98747939145517 |
| ENSG00000002549.12 | LAP3 | 852.041745825179 | -0.254029783752867 | 0.0719977839970102 | -3.52830003439294 | 0.000418237809317195 | 0.00642614461337485 |
| ENSG00000002587.10 | HS3ST1 | 2.57897400765919 | 0.0144688913294909 | 0.777073236085079 | 0.0186197267613869 | 0.985144465883661 | NA |
| ENSG00000002745.13 | WNT16 | 16.1270763411369 | -0.00537408371714073 | 0.30400368641928 | -0.0176776925978747 | 0.985895976595832 | 0.993837819473658 |
| ENSG00000002746.15 | HECW1 | 46.6208055525063 | -0.273107000095639 | 0.217402004605246 | -1.25623036729372 | 0.209032459705226 | 0.438247467420401 |
| ENSG00000002834.18 | LASP1 | 2081.18262394114 | 0.25353664096991 | 0.0740348392744757 | 3.42455853831129 | 0.000615799164096869 | 0.00849490484558848 |
| ENSG00000002919.15 | SNX11 | 630.57793127673 | 0.0459782434754682 | 0.105868331615849 | 0.434296477272386 | 0.664073161622284 | 0.820640102421514 |
| ENSG00000002933.9 | TMEM176A | 1.2826428629398 | -0.208251902266481 | 1.04854999265659 | -0.198609416551381 | 0.842568287014726 | NA |
| ENSG00000003056.8 | M6PR | 2075.74758354412 | -0.298258970884233 | 0.0818583611419073 | -3.64359812148181 | 0.000268853092542719 | 0.00454947228687621 |
| ENSG00000003096.14 | KLHL13 | 536.62234593866 | 0.158623735269079 | 0.107348560798392 | 1.47765125204599 | 0.139501148591557 | 0.348980620824275 |
| ENSG00000003137.8 | CYP26B1 | 287.854716803642 | -0.0740116292474195 | 0.109594213807301 | -0.675324240908867 | 0.499469786095141 | 0.712657283500843 |
| ENSG00000003147.19 | ICA1 | 535.667848254903 | -0.143475821995906 | 0.0973591074296888 | -1.47367643134487 | 0.140568731550252 | 0.350583904431043 |

Comment: Your code and data do not reproduce your error for me. The code runs without error. In addition, your use of a `text` argument inside `aes` is incorrect and does not produce anything. What are you trying to do, exactly? Can you show a screenshot of your plot so far?

Comment: I just updated my code. I'm using plotly to make an interactive graph. 

Just to reiterate, my code works fine on my Mac, but not on my Linux machine. I'm not sure if there is something wrong with the formatting of my code? Buggy? Or if this could be rewritten somehow?

Comment: you probably have checked this, but are you sure you have the exact same version of ggplot2 and plotly packages on the two machines?  I only ask because recently I ran into a similar issue where my plotly code was tripping on another machine simply because I hadn't updated to that machine's plotly version to the same version used on the development machine

Comment: I double-checked again, but yes, I'm running the same version of ggplot2, plotly, dplyr between the two machines. Also, I'm using the same version of R.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, as your code works fine. The only thing that was not working was `"WebGL is not supported by your browser"`. I solved it forcing RStudio to use 'Desktop OpenGL'. In RStudio, I went to [Tools/Global Options.../Advanced] and choosing 'Desktop OpenGL' in Rendering engine.

Sample code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)



plot_total <-demo %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  ggplot(aes(log2(baseMean), log2FoldChange, color=padj < 0.01,
             text = paste(" log2(baseMean):", formatC(log2(baseMean), format = "e", digits = 2), "\n",
                          "log2FoldChange:", formatC(log2FoldChange, format = "e", digits = 2), "\n",
                          "Gene Name:", Gene, "\n",
                          "EnsGeneID:", ENSG))) +
  geom_point(data = . %>% filter(!padj<0.01), cex = 0.1, size=0.1) +
  geom_point(data = . %>% filter(is.na(padj)), cex = 0.1, size=0.1) +
  geom_point(data = . %>% filter(padj<0.01), cex = 1, size=1) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("FALSE" = "#30B7BC", "TRUE" = "#DE653A", "NA" = "#B3B3B3")) +
  labs(title = "Treated vs. Control", x = "log2Expression") +
  theme_bw() +
  NULL

ggplotly(plot_total,
         tooltip = "text",
         type = 'scattergl') %>% 
  config(displaylogo = FALSE,
         modeBarButtonsToRemove = c('sendDataToCloud', 'select2d', 'lasso2d')) %>% 
  toWebGL()
```

Plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was getting this error was because the `df` didn't contain `NA` under padj column for my particular dataset, so it was trying to filter what wasn't there. Adding an `if/else` statement fixed.